# Homogeneity test in survival meta-analysis with adjusted HR

Tags: survival, cox-model, meta-analysis, likelihood, heterogeneity

I was wondering what was the way to measure heterogeneity in a survival meta-analysis.
I have for each study, an hazard ratio calculated with a penalized cox model (`coxphf` function, `coxphf` library in R) for my interest covariate and some covariates of adjustment.

My precedent way of doing, in a model without covariate of adjustment, was to compare the likelihood of the different studies with the likelihood calculated on the total database:
$$Likelihood_{(Study\ 1)} + ... + Likelihood_{(Study\ k)}  - Likelihood_{(TotalDataBase)}$$
The result was compared with a $Chi^2$  distribution of $(k-1)$ degrees of freedom.

But this prodecure does not work when using a model which includes interest and adjustment covariates and  calculated on a penalized likelihood.

Any suggestion for my case ?

Thanks :-)